# What does $M_n(F)$ means

Tags: matrices, notation, definition

What does $M_n(F)$ means? I am a new comer to matrix algebra. Please help, thank you. Thank you so much. $F$ stands for vector space guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the precise context, one can only guess. But since you write that you are a beginner in matrix algebra, I guess stat $F$ is a *field* and that $M_n(F)$ denotes the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $F$.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I need! Thanks!